# SDK Manager is greyed out

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Searched for other answers but didn't find an exact answer.

I just installed Android Studio and followed exactly the directions that are displayed here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio

When I move on to the next page here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html it states that I should "In Eclipse or Android Studio, click SDK Manager in the toolbar". But the Icon "SDK Manager" is greyed out.

I am running ubuntu 64-bit 14.04

JDK runs fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the current versions of Android Studio have been released without SDK included by default. You can download it here http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz, and install in a folder different from your AS installation since it's important now.
AS usually asks you for a path to SDK location if it cannot find it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you may need to right click the sdk manager .exe file and run as administrator for AS to recognize your downloads. This is sometimes an issue.

Comment: Thanks Lukos I'll keep that in mind for my windows machine. I'll try it out and come back to you. The thing is, it is stated (when I download the AS) that everything is included in that package(including the Android SDK).

Comment: If you cannot find "sdk" folder in the archive you've downloaded, chances are it's not included.

Comment: Note for others:  After you point Android Studio to the SDK location (which you manually setup), the SDK Manager becomes immediately available from inside Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
My setup is behind a proxy. So the studio init was failing.
So i added `disable.android.first.run=true` this line in idea.properties in android-studio/bin
It worked and studio was launched, but then i saw that SDK Manager is grayed out.

My Problem was fixed when i removed the `disable.android.first.run=true` line and started the studio again.

Please also keep in mind that i had to add the below lines for proxy in

```
studio64.vmoptions and studio.vmoptions
-Dhttps.proxyPort=port
-Dhttps.proxyHost=host
-Dhttps.proxyUser=username
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=password
```

Hope this helps