# Make sure that 'Google APIs' is up to date in the SDK manager for API 18

Tags: java, android, github, intellij-idea

I try to contribute to [robolectric gitHub](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric)

I try to import to intellij, but I get this error:

```
❯ ./scripts/install-dependencies.rb                                                                                                                                                                                                        [16:44:28]
com.google.android.maps:maps not found!
Make sure that 'Google APIs' is up to date in the SDK manager for API 18.
```

i have the SDK API 18 and yet it wont' run the requested cmd

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: the SDK-manager is grayed out in my intellij

Comment: Have you installed the SDK? I found this by searching your _exact_ comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874119/sdk-manager-is-greyed-out

Comment: I should use android studio? that's what the asker did.

Comment: Android Studio is built on IDEA. The principles should be the same. Either way, I think you'll need the Android SDK since it's an Android project.

Comment: please look at my updated question. i have the SDK API 18 and yet it wont' run the requested cmd